# In c++11 why not right to use moved variable after std::move?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, rvalue-reference

As `std::move(v)` is merely a cast like

```
static_cast<T&&>(v)
```

where `T` is the type of `v`. But why the **moved variable** not a `reference` of the original object?

For example, when `o1` is "moved" to `o2`, why can't we access the `str_` of `o2` through `o1.str_` any more?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass {
  std::string str_;
  MyClass(MyClass const &) = delete;
  MyClass &operator=(MyClass const &) = delete;
  MyClass(MyClass &&o) : str_(std::move(o.str_)) {}
  MyClass(std::string const &str) : str_(str) {}
};

int main(void) {
  MyClass o1 = MyClass("o1");
  MyClass o2(std::move(o1));
    std::cout << "o1: " << o1.str_ << "\n"
        << "o2: " << o2.str_ << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
o1: 
o2: o1
```

### update:

It seems that when I change

```
MyClass(MyClass &&o) : str_(std::move(o.str_)) {}
```

to

```
MyClass(MyClass &&o) : str_(o.str_) {}
```

the output would be:

```
o1: o1
o2: o1
```

So the root cause is the "std::string" move? But why this makes different?

Comment: What do you mean by "access the `str_` of `o2` through `o1.str_`"?

Comment: @WiSaGaN: The OP thinks that the second line of `main` magically makes `o2` become the variable `o1`. This isn't how C++ works, though.

Comment: @KerrekSB Could you tell why `o1.str_` is no longer `o1` at the end of the codeblock?

Comment: Because it has been moved-from.

Comment: @KerrekSB I made an update, would you please tell the details as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Well, with your change you're copying `str_` rather than moving it... The move constructor only gives you the *opportunity* to move, but you still have to do the work yourself.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah, I see that *opportunity*(for example, the move constructor can be defined exactly as its copy constructor). So in this sense, does that mean **whenever** I see a `move`, I should not use the moved variable any more for safety?

Comment: In response to your question about why the moved-to variable (`o2`) isn't a `reference`: references have nothing to do with moving, and the type of a variable (which *includes* whether or not it's a reference) is determined by what you *declare* the variable to be (in this case `o2` is declared to be of type `MyClass`), *not* by how you construct it--and in fact references aren't even really constructed--i.e., no constructor is called to make them (since they're just pointers internally, not actual objects).

Comment: If you want `o2` to be a reference, you must explicitly declare it that way: either `MyClass& o2` or `auto& o2` would work here. (Or `MyClass&&`, which I think would compile, but would be dangerous.) I think you can also get an r-value reference (`MyClass&&`) by using `decltype` here, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's forget about your class for now, and just take an `std::string` as an example.

```
std::string s1{"Hello, World!"};  // 1
std::string s2{s1};               // 2
std::string s3{std::move(s1)};    // 3
```

On line 1 you've constructed an `std::string` object. On line 2 you're *copying* `s1` to `s2`. Now both `s1` and `s2` will contain their own copies of the string `"Hello, World!"`. This copy is being done by the copy constructor of `std::string` (or `std::basic_string<char>`) which does not modify the argument.

```
basic_string(basic_string const& other);
```

On line 3 you're *moving* the contents of `s1` to `s3`. In order to do this, you first cast `s1` to `std::string&&` (this is what `std::move` does). Because of this cast, the call will now match `std::string`'s move constructor, instead of the copy constructor like the previous line.

```
basic_string(basic_string&& other) noexcept;
```

This constructor, because it's always called with an rvalue instance of the string, has license to steal resources from the argument. So internally the constructor will simply copy over some pointers to the memory that was allocated<sup>†</sup> by `s1` to store the string, and set the state of the `s1` instance such that it is now empty. Thus `s3` now *owns* the string.

The same things are happening when you move the `string` data member within your class instance. That's why the moved from `std::string` object appears empty when you print it.

<sup>†</sup> The operations performed are different if the `std::string` implementation uses *small string optimization*, but that is just an implementation detail. Conceptually, both cases work as described above.

Comment: Still confused: why the constructor bothers to `set the state of s1`, but not just let it as it was?

Comment: @HongxuChen Suppose the string were pointing to data on the heap.  If the move constructor didn't fix s1, then both s3 and s1 would be pointing to the same location.  When s3 went out of scope, it frees the data it points to.  The same happens when s1 goes out of scope.  If they point at the same location, that's a double free bug.

Comment: @Nevin So it's the extra operations that the constructor internally does that makes the difference and it has nothing to do with `std::move` itself, right? Is there a scenario that guarantees the use of the moved variable(like `s1`, `o1`) to be correct?

Comment: @Hongxu `std::move` is nothing but `static_cast<T&&>`. By doing it you're stating that the function you pass the `move`d object to has permission to grab the source object's internals. Strictly speaking, `std::string`'s move constructor need not set the source to an empty string, because the standard only states the source is in a *valid but unspecified state*. But if it wasn't set to empty, you'd run into double deletion problems like Nevin said. You can use the moved from variable in any way that doesn't violate any preconditions for that use.

Comment: @Hongxu For instance, checking whether the moved from string is empty is fine, but using `operator[]` to access elements is not, because `empty()` doesn't have any preconditions, but `operator[]` requires `pos <= size()`, where `pos` is the argument to `operator[]`.

Answer (score 8):

You are quite right that `std::move` just casts its argument to rvalue-reference.

But any function receiving such an rvalue-reference has explicit license to pillage it in order to more efficiently do its work, it just must leave it in some arbitrary valid state.

You can certainly keep using it though, just be aware how little "some arbitrary valid state" guarantees.

This pillaging of the moved object makes move-semantics move-semantics, and was explicit goal.

Comment: Sorry I haven't got your ideas. I made an update for the question, would you please tell more details for this example?

Comment: Due to recent technical problems with SO, I got your message far too late, Praetorian already added an answer with all the examples one could want for your ammended question...

Answer (score 0):

Because the implementation for most move constructors really moves the data from one object to another and invalidates the data on the first object.

This is why it is called moving and not copying.