# Understanding when shared_ptr reference counts are incremented when passing into a function

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have the following `Container` class

```
template <typename T>
class Container
{
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> items_;
public:
    void addItem(std::shared_ptr<T> item)
    {
        std::cout << "useCount addItem pre: " << item.use_count() << std::endl;
        items_.push_back(std::move(item));
        std::cout << "useCount addItem post: " << item.use_count() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

and I'm calling it like this

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::unique_ptr<Container<std::string>> container = std::make_unique<Container<std::string>>();

    std::shared_ptr<std::string> s = std::make_shared<std::string>("hello");

    std::cout << "useCount main pre: " << s.use_count() << std::endl;

    container->addItem(s);

    std::cout << "useCount main post: " << s.use_count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I get

```
useCount main pre: 1
useCount addItem pre: 2
useCount addItem post: 0
useCount main post: 2
```

Line by line...

1. Makes sense, there's only one reference to `s` as soon as its defined
2. Makes sense, `s` gets copied into `item` so its reference count is incremented by 1
3. I've given `items_` ownership of `item`, so the reference count shouldn't change since `addItem` has relinquished ownership and transferred it to `items_`. I expect the reference count to be 2, once from `main` and once from `items_`. Instead it's 0.
4. Makes sense as long as one reference is from `main` and one reference is from `items_`.

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: In #3, you are looking at a variable that has been moved from. `item` is holding a null pointer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It doesn't hold null. It is empty. There is a (very subtle) difference between a non-empty shared pointer that holds null, and an empty shared pointer which doesn't hold anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::move` moves the item out of that variable into another one. As one author put it, it "[has explicit license to pillage [the variable]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25341761/10957435)." For [most std objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32346143/10957435), that puts the original object into an unspecified state. However, it appears [`std:shared_ptr` is an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34772219/10957435) in that it leaves the object in an empty state.

What all this boils down to is that you can't treat `item` as the same reference to `s` anymore after the move. It is in a different state, storing something else. That's why your reference count is off.

If instead you had done this:

```
std::cout << "useCount addItem post: " << items_.back().use_count() << std::endl;
```

You would have got the expected output of `2`.

Answer (score 4):

After a shared pointer has been moved from, it shall be empty. The use count of an empty shared pointer is 0.

From another point of view, you were expecting that at that point, `main`, and `items_` owned the object (which is correct), but if they are counted in the `use_count` of the pointer `item`, then that would be a total of three shared pointers owning the object. That contradicts with your expectation of 2. Of course, this is explained by the fact that `item` no longer owns the object, so its use count is actually no longer related to other pointers that do own it.

Comment: Thanks @eeronika I appreciate that your answer showed the flaw in my logic, but I accepted @Chipster 's answer since it provided some extra information about the behavior of `std::shared_ptr`